# org.jdom.Document cannot be resolve. It's indirectly referenced form required .class file

Tags: jdom

I try to work on RSS and receive the following error: org.jdom.Document cannot be resolve. It's indirectly referenced form required .class file.

I already added the jdom jar to my build path and tried different version but nothing worked.

I checked in the jdom jar, org.jdom.Document is not there, but jdom.src.org.jdom is there instead. If I extracted the source code of the jdom lib to my project and changed the package name to org.jdom, it would resolve the error.

However, I want to use the jar file only, not the actual source.Can anyone help me to resolve the error? Thanks!

Comment: If you have it fixed you should really post up what you did so anyone else will be able to benefit from it if they get the same issue. Cos "I got if fixed" ain't gonna help them

Answer (score 3):

Instead of JDOM 2,x, after download JDOM 1.1.3 and added the build/jdom-1.1.3.jar file into Eclipse build path, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see you 'have it fixed'.... but, in case anyone else runs in to the same issue....

I expect that you have the jdom.zip file, not the jdom.jar file. The jdom.zip file is the distribution, and in the jdom/build directory you will find the actual jdom.jar file (or, depending on the version, jdom-1.1.3.jar ).

JDOM 2.x has a different release format (a zip file with a few jars....).

It is confusing, thus the different release format in 2.x

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the Document or other classes which I was trying to import got changed under jdom2 in my jar. ie downloaded the jdom jars and added in my build path. So to import i changed to "import org.jdom2.Document" instead of "org.jdom.Document".

Check the class files in your jar package "jdom-2.0.6.jar" or in your specific version.

Dennis